# Ring of endomorphisms of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

One article on elliptic curves over finite fields makes the following claim:
"Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$. The rings End$_{\mathbb{F}_q}(E)$ and End$_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}(E)$ are
either complex quadratic orders or maximal orders in $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty,p}$" where $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty,p}$ is a quartenion algebra that ramifies only at $p$ and $\infty$.

Other article mentions that "It is known that
End$(E)$ is an order in a finite-dimensional division algebra over $Q$".

Apparently these things are meant to be know, but i couldn't find any proof for these claims. Can someone explain any of those or provide me a source?

Comment: It is because with $\phi^*$ the dual isogeny $\phi^*\phi$ and $\phi^*+\phi$ are norms and traces $End(E) \to \Bbb{Z}$ and there are not many $\Bbb{Q}$-algebras having such trace and (non-negative) norm.

Comment: I don't understand, are they norms and traces of what? What is the application from the endomorphisms into the integers?

Comment: Given isogeny $\phi$ there is a unique group homomorphism $\phi^*$ (on torsion subgroups of the elliptic curves) such that $\phi^*\phi = [d], d = \deg(\phi)$, that homomorphism is an isogeny, then for $\phi \in End(E)$, $N( \phi) =\phi^* \phi, Tr(\phi) = \phi^*+\phi$, from the $2\times 2$ profinite integer matrix representation of group endomorphisms $Tr(\phi)$ is (multiplication by) a profinite integer and since it is an algebraic endomorphism it is (multiplication by) an integer $\in End(E) \cap \Bbb{Z}$. This is the key idea, the technical parts are proven eg. in Silverman.

Comment: I forgot to say $(ab)^*= b^* a^*, a^{**} = a$ (same property as the matrix transpose and the  quaternion conjugate)

Comment: IIRC this is explained in J. Silverman's book.

Comment: I believe that these facts are “classical”, having appeared in Deuring’s paper “Die Typen der Multiplikatorenringe elliptischer Funktionenkörper” in 1941.

Comment: Here is a sketch of a proof that I came up with. First of all one starts by showing that the endomorphism algebra of $E$ is a division algebra (every isogeny has a dual isogeny such that the composition is equals multiplication by the degree). Then one notes that it acts non-trivially (and so faithfully) on the $\ell$-adic Tate module of $E$ for all $\ell \not=p$. This means that it's $\ell$-adic completion is a $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-algebra contained in $M_2(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ and therefore it is equal to $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell^2}$ or $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}^2$ or to $M_2(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ ...

Comment: ...(note that it cannot just be $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ because of the Frobenius isogeny). So now all one has to do is to exclude $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and real quadratic fields as the endomorphism algebra. We can exclude $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ by noting that $M_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ cannot act on the $p$-divisible group $E[p^{\infty}]$ (because it is not isomorphic to $H^2$ for some $p$-divisible group $H$). I guess one can exclude the real quadratic field case by lifting to characteristic zero?

Comment: Thanks, i found the explanation in the J. Silverman's book.